# cat: invalid option -- 'a'

Tags: linux, shell

I have some c files and  common.txt in "Abb/test" folder and temp.txt in "Abb" folder.I want to copy content of common.txt in header of all the c files. I am using the following unix shell script code:-

```
for i in 'find test -name *.c'; do cat test/common.txt $i > temp.txt && mv temp.txt $i; done
```

but it is giving error "cat: invalid option -- 'a' "

can someone help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several grave problems in your code.

Your code with newlines for readability:

```
for i in 'find test -name *.c'
do
  cat test/common.txt $i > temp.txt && mv temp.txt $i
done
```

Problem: wrong quotes for shell substitution.

```
for i in `find test -name '*.c'`
do
  cat test/common.txt $i > temp.txt && mv temp.txt $i
done
```

Problem: not quoting `$i`.

```
for i in `find test -name '*.c'`
do
  cat test/common.txt "$i" > temp.txt && mv temp.txt "$i"
done
```

Problem: using for loop to loop over filenames.

```
find test -name '*.c' | while read -r filename
do
  cat test/common.txt "$filename" > temp.txt && mv temp.txt "$filename"
done
```

Comment: Probably even possible to do a `find ... -exec` instead of looping through the results of `find`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when trying to use `cp` command on execution of my custom uploaded shell script and after a lot of time searching for reason I finally find out my script file had **`windows line endings`** and after converting them to **`unix format`** the problem solved.